# Is disabling all user accounts during a change set a good practice?

Tags: administration, bestpractice, change-set

Just wanted to know under what circumstances you would need to disable all users during a change-set in Salesforce.

Some of my colleagues are for it and some against the idea as you risk locking the Admin account if not done properly!

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't lock (intentionally) your own account. It's absolutely impossible to deactivate your own account or change your profile to a non-admin profile. Of course, it's not infallible; you can still set impossible login ranges or login hours. Even then, there's a policy you can invoke to recover your account (see [000004627](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Changing-the-System-Administrator-for-my-Salesforce-account&language=en_US)), but that's more of a manual process.

Generally, it just doesn't matter. Users can continue to access a system while a deployment is in progress. This means that it's pretty hard to screw up. If you absolutely need to lock accounts, just freeze everyone that's not an admin. Most of the time, you don't need to care, because the deployment will fix any problems. In those rare cases where it does matter, make sure you freeze your users. It won't matter for most cases anyways, and for those rare cases it does matter, you've probably already accounted for it. Just make sure you don't restrict the admin profile, and you'll be okay.